# The number of the matrices in the complex entries fits the equation.

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

In this question we consider 2 × 2 matrices over C.
The number of different diagonal 2 × 2 matrices D (with complex entries) such that $D^3=-125 \cdot I_2\,$ is ? (Reminder: $I_2$ is the unit matrix of order 2×2). I can just find $2$ ,but the answer is wrong.

Thank you very much.

I have to describe my process simply. First I set a complex number $a+bi$ as the $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ of the matrix. Second I try to find the solutions of $(a+bi)^3=-125$ and I can get $a=5/2$ and $b=\pm\, 5\cdot\sqrt{3}/2$ so I can only find $2$. Hoping my description is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the formatting, you can find more MathJax tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To the question... 1) You missed the third solution $a=-5$, $b=0$. 2) The problem does not require that $a_{11}=a_{22}$.

Comment: Ok，thank you very much.

Comment: -125 has three third rots over the complex numbers.